# I lost my wordpress site url's, can i get it from wordpress backup file

Tags: wordpress, web, frontend

recently I moved on my site from Wordpress to PHP CMS. forgot to backup my old URLs. can I have the chance to get my URL's from WordPress backup file?

Comment: All wordpress content can be found in the database dump.

Answer (score 0):

If you have wordpress(your old site) database then you can find your website url from **wp_options** table and all other page and post url from **wp_post** table